# Transfer user information on net.tcp wcf context

Tags: c#, wcf, tcp

I want to transfer data from client services to server services but I don't want to transfer it as parameter in each call of service functions
I tried to insert the data in `OutgoingMessageProperties`, but I didn't get it on server side, I got an error: `A property with the name 'Token' is not present`,
why? 
If I'm not allowed to use it why it has the `Add` function?
The protocol I'm using is `net.tcp`

Client Side:

```
GeneralServicesClient Ret = new GeneralServicesClient(Consts.WcfGeneralChannels.TcpIp);
using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(Ret.InnerChannel))
         {
             OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add("Token", Guid.NewGuid());
             Ret.Func();
         }
```

Server Side:

```
  System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext identity = System.ServiceModel.ServiceSecurityContext.Current;
  OperationContext context = OperationContext.Current;
  MessageProperties messageProperties = context.IncomingMessageProperties;
  string token = messageProperties["Token"].ToString();//throw error: A property with the name 'Token' is not present
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put your service call inside the using.

```
GeneralServicesClient Ret = new GeneralServicesClient(Consts.WcfGeneralChannels.TcpIp);
using (OperationContextScope scope = new OperationContextScope(Ret.InnerChannel))
     {
         OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageProperties.Add("Token", Guid.NewGuid());
         Ret.Do();
     }
```

Comment: thanks, but it didn't help, the error is still thrown, I edit the question, see the changes

Comment: @stmnmn what if you push the user information to the headers instead? as in OperationContext.Current.OutgoingMessageHeaders.Add(...)

Comment: you are right that I had to call the service function in the using clause, but that is not good to me, cause I wrote the using in a base class, where I didn't know the function that should be run. thanks.